# having a java code output error

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public  class StrictDescending
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        final int SENTINEL = 1000;
        Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);
        int prev = n.nextInt();

        if (prev >= SENTINEL)
        {
            System.out.println("Empty list");
            return;
        }
        while (true) 
        {
            int next = n.nextInt();
            if (next >= SENTINEL) {
                break;
            } else if (next >= prev) {
                System.out.println("No, the list is not in descending order.");
            }
            prev = next;
        }
        System.out.println("Yes, the list in in descending order.");
    }
}
```

I am trying to run this program and go through a list of 3 digit integers and when the folowing 3 digit integer is not descending i want to print no the list is not descending, also if the list is in descending at it comes to a non 3 digit numbr like 1000 i want to print yes the list is descending my output works but when i put in a non descending list of integers it spits out two output statements

for this input

```
150 140 140 120 1000
```

i get

```
No, the list is not in descending order.

No, the list is not in descending order.

Yes, the list in in descending order.
```

when I just want

```
No, the list is not in descending order.
```

Comment: how would i fix this?

Comment: Look at the link I provided and accept the duplicate

Comment: sounds about right.  This line will be executed with every call:  System.out.println("Yes, the list in in descending order.");

Comment: so which line do i take out?

Comment: @user6451702 "*but when i put in a non descending list of integers it spits out two output statements*" could you post example of input and output you are getting and what output you ware expecting?

Comment: just added it to my question up above

Comment: Ah.  Does program need to stop after one such list?

Comment: it needs to stop soon as the numbers are not descending and when 1000 is entered but if the numbers before 1000 are descending then it should print yes the numbers are descending

Comment: You need to rethink your logic. If you want to stop your loop after printing `No, the list is not in descending order.` then you need to `brake` (or change condition in loop from `while(true)` to something like `while(isDescending)` and when you will figure out that it is no longer descending set that boolean flag to `false`). Also printing `Yes, the list in in descending order.
` is always executed because it is outside of any conditions.

Answer (score 0):

If i've understood your problem description correctly, you can solve it by setting a flag, and use it as condition to print either "Yes, the list is in descending order." or "No, the list is not in descending order."

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StrictDescending {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int SENTINEL = 1000;
        Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);
        int prev = n.nextInt();

        if (prev >= SENTINEL) {
            System.out.println("Empty list");
            return;
        }
        boolean descending = true;
        while (true) {
            int next = n.nextInt();
            if (next >= SENTINEL) {
                break;
            } else if (next >= prev) {
                descending = false;
            }
            prev = next;
        }
        if (descending) {
            System.out.println("Yes, the list is in descending order.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("No, the list is not in descending order.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 150 140 140 120 1000 for those outputs I am still getting Yes, the list is in descending order.  but 140 and 140 means it is not descending

Comment: @user6451702 Ha good catch, i didn't test duplicates.  It's because I messed up, will fix.

Comment: @user6451702  Is that what you meant?  It's mostly your own code, I just added the boolean logic.  If you have any questions about that, don't hesitate to ask.